# Eigenvectors of spin-spin coupling Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

We want to find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian, $H = \vec{\sigma_1}.\vec{\sigma_2}$ , where the subscript indicates the particle number.

The usual way to go about it is to find the representation of the Hamiltonian in the vector space $\mathcal{1}\otimes \mathcal{2}$. In the basis of the eigenvectors of $\sigma_{1z}$ and $\sigma_{2z}$, we see that $H$ takes the form:

$\pmatrix{1& 0 &0 & 0 \\ 0 &-1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 &2& -1& 0\\ 0&0&0&1}$

This gives eigenvalues of $1$ (multiplicity $3$), and -$3$(multiplicity $1$). Two of the eigenvectors are un-entangled states.

Now, another seemingly valid way to solve this problem is to assert that for an un-entangled eigenstate of $H$, $\Psi_1 \otimes\Psi_2$, $\Psi_1$ must be an eigenstate of $\sigma_{1x}+\sigma_{1y}+\sigma_{1z}$ and  $\Psi_2$ must be an eigenstate of $\sigma_{2x}+\sigma_{2y}+\sigma_{2z}$. If we proceed to diagonalize the respective operators and take the tensor product of their eigenvectors, we see that this formulation gives a total of $4$ independent eigenstates of $H$, with eigenvalues $\pm3$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1. Your suggested eigenvalues 1 (3x) and 3 (1x) cannot be correct as the sum of these must equal the trace of the matrix, which is $0$.  2.  Why should $\Psi_1$ be eigenstate of the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of that matrix are 1 (with multiplicity 3) and **-3** (with multiplicity 1).  All of the eigenvectors are pure states.

I think the problem in the second half of your question is, as @ZeroTheHero mentions, that $\Psi_i$ so defined are not necessarily eigenstates of $\sigma_{ix}+\sigma_{iy}+\sigma_{iz}$ (for $i=1,2$).

Hope this helps!

Comment: The Hamiltonian is: $\sigma_{1x} \otimes \sigma_{2x}+\sigma_{1y} \otimes \sigma_{2y}+\sigma_{1z} \otimes \sigma_{2z}$. It seems that a pure state of the form: $\Psi_1 \otimes \Psi_2$, where say $\Psi_i$ is an eigenstate of $\sigma_{ix}+\sigma_{iy}+\sigma_{iz}$ should also be an eigenstate of $H$, given that the operators in the two spaces act only on their respective vectors. I am definitely missing something.

Comment: Ah!  What you are missing is that $\Psi_1\otimes\Psi_2$ as you have defined is an eigenstate of $(\sigma_{1x}+\sigma_{1y}+\sigma_{1z})\otimes(\sigma_{2x}+\sigma_{2y}+\sigma_{2z})$, but this is not equal to $\sigma_{1x}\otimes\sigma_{2x}+\sigma_{1y}\otimes\sigma_{2y}+\sigma_{1z}\otimes\sigma_{2z}$ (tensor products obey the distributive law).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!